# Grid tables - quantity of rows AX 2012 R3

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I've created form with two grids. Each grid has got diffrent data source without any relation between them. When I'm creating a range on DS1 its affecting not only grid1 with ds1 but also grid2 with another data source. It's cutting records in grid 2 to quantity of records in grid 1 after using range.

Can someone tell me how to avoid this effect? I want to have 2 independent grids in one form.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate Dyna-Links on the form (Personalize - Query).

Clear them with [`clearDynalinks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/querybuilddatasource.cleardynalinks.aspx).

```cs
public void init()
{
    super();

    MyTable1_ds.queryBuildDataSource().clearDynalinks();
    MyTable2_ds.queryBuildDataSource().clearDynalinks();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work - in form init() method or data source init().

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the DataSource property on the second grid control is set to the second datasource.

This is a common error, consistent with the behaviour you described.

Comment: Data sources are set property - double checked

Comment: Can we see an export?